# preg_match differences in PHP 5.3.2 vs. PHP 5.2.1

Tags: preg-match, php-5.3

Not much of a PHP/regex guy, but am puzzled as to why some functionality in a PHP Web framework has stopped working since moving to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (PHP 5.3.2) from Ubuntu 8.04 (PHP 5.2.1).

Using xdebug and remote debugging, I was able to step through to a function in a GD library that checks to see if the file in question has a mime type that can thumbnailed:

```
function liberty_gd_can_thumbnail_image( $pMimeType ) {
$ret = FALSE;
if( !empty( $pMimeType )) {
    $ret = preg_match( '/^image/i', $pMimeType );
}
return $ret;
}
```

I've confirmed that the value of $pMimeType is "i" and changing that line to `$ret = true;` resolves the issue, but am unsure as to why that would not work now.  Hopefully someone with better regex/PHP skills can assist here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is looking for a MIME type that begins with `image`, e.g. `image/gif` or `image/jpeg`. If `$pmimeType` is `"i"` then that legitimately fails the test. `i` is not a valid MIME type, let alone an image MIME type.

I doubt there's anything wrong with the regex matching. I'd look instead at where this bogus `i` MIME type is coming from.

Comment: Ah, ok, the "/i" kind of threw me there, thought it was a sed-like "image or i" type expression.

Comment: @gravyface Ah yes, that is a flag which makes the regex case insensitive. The regex itself is between the slashes.

Comment: Yup, and you're right: "i" as a MIME type doesn't make any sense (kinda glossed over that; was thinking "i = image")